# "On the flatcar" versus "on to the flatcar" versus "on to flatcar" versus "on flatcar"

Tags: grammaticality

> Mike helps John to get on the flatcar.

> Mike helps John to get on to the flatcar.

> Mike helps John to get on flatcar.

> Mike helps John to get on to flatcar.

> Mike helps John to get onto flatcar.

Note, I'm referring to a [flatcar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatcar), so you can't use "get in".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you need *the*; without it *flatcar* becomes a name for something, and probably should be capitalized.

Second, "getting **on** the flatcar" and "getting **onto** the flatcar" are interchangeable, but "getting **on to** the flatcar" means something else.

For example if you had to wash the flatcar and the boxcar, you might say, "I need to finish up this boxcar and then I can get on to the flatcar."  In this case the phrasal verb is "get on" and the prepositional phrase is "to the flatcar" and *get on* means to *move on* to the next thing on the list.